# How do I turn off the automatic focus shift after "git pull" in PyCharm?

Tags: python, git, pycharm

I've noticed that sometimes when I do a `git pull` from within the terminal in PyCharm, the focus will shift when the merge completes to whichever file I was editing before I clicked into the terminal. This seems to only happen when the `pull` command requires a merge and not when I'm "already up-to-date".

This is so infuriating, because I almost always have a few more commands to enter into the terminal after pulling from the repo before I want to start editing files, and I almost always end up typing `git checkout ...` inside some random file.

I've searched high and low through the settings, but I can't seem to find anything relevant. How do I turn this focus shift feature off??